# Resource availability in Pedestrian library

Tags: anylogic

is there a way to make the waiting time of an agent based on a resource availability in the Pedestrian Library  ? to make agent wait until he got served by a certain resource ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use such an arrangement:

[image]

It might make you animation slightly more difficult, but it should work depending on the specifics of your model.

Comment: Thank you Emile , i am using the ResourceSentTo block in such arrangement and keep telling the following Error " root.resourceSendTo:
Agent is not registered with the network and cannot send resource units "
where does such error can originate from and how to solve this matter down  ?

Comment: Can you move this to a new question with more details to be able to provide a better answer?